# Calling return of parent function from the completion handler

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, networking

I have a network task performing function in `func application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:)`. The `rootViewController` by default is a `UITabBarController`. I want to sync my brands list by downloading it from server on app launch. My code is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        .......
        .......
        .......

        APICaller.getBrandsAndOutletList(withAuthToken: "87087fa228dee4fbbacada66683eb6fa94d4d8968dbc8121d275afe75a79e4b6d",
            success: { (result) in
                let rCode = result["rcode"] as! String
                //If user revoked or access revoked for the user
                guard rCode == "200" else {
                    let updateAppVC = UpdateAppViewController(nibName: "UpdateAppViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
                    if rCode == "401" {
                        let userStatus = result["status"] as! String
                        print(userStatus)
                        updateAppVC.message = userStatus
                        updateAppVC.buttonTitle = "Re-login"
                        self.window?.rootViewController = updateAppVC
                        //POINT-1
                        return
                    }else {
                        updateAppVC.message = "Some error"
                        updateAppVC.buttonTitle = "Retry"
                        self.window?.rootViewController = updateAppVC
                        //POINT-2
                        return
                    }

                }

                let brands = result["brands"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(brands)
                //POINT-3

            }) { (errorMessage) in
                print(errorMessage)
                //POINT-4
        }

        return true //POINT-5
    }
```

Right now, what happens is the network request is made and the list downloading takes place in background. The `return true` is executed and the `tabBar` appears. Then after the request is completed, `success:` or `failure:` block is called.

What I want to achieve that, I don't want to `return true` before completing the request. So don't want to call the `return true` at POINT-5. Instead, I want to call that `return true` at POINT-1,2,3,4, i.e., when my network request will be completed. Can I do that, if yes then how?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? What would returning `false` mean to you? If you don't return `true` until the background process is finished it will block the main thread and the app will appear unresponsive. Can you describe what you want to happen while the background task is running?

Comment: @Michael I dont mind UI to look unresponsive while the Background task is running. I just want to `return true` inside my closure. How can I call this `return true` inside the closure, i.e., at the Points specified, which are inside the closure body?

Comment: You can't. If you `return` inside the closure, it is the closure that is returning, not the main function. You would see this more obviously if the closure was a separate function. You need to display something while the background task runs, otherwise you'd just have a black screen and the user would be wondering why your app wasn't launching. What if it takes a minute for the task to finish? What is wrong with returning `true` immediately while the task is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a completion block to create a return value for the above method.

From the above code it sounds like you want to switch screens on the basis of the data from server during launch. And you don't want to show the Tab bar controller showing while the call happens. What you can do is have a splash screen view controller (or a screen simple activity indicator) and set it as the root view controller until the request round trips.

Comment: Exactly what I was confused about!